# Not able to locate the Submit while using Selenium Web Driver

Tags: java, selenium, struts2, junit

I am trying to implement selenium testing in one of my struts2 application for the login form.The login form has 2 textfield(username & password) and a submit button as below

```
<tr>
<td><s:submit value="Login" /></td>
</tr>
```

The selenium test class as below

```
package home_page;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class OpenURL {

@Test
public void openSoftwareTesting(){

    WebDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    _driver.get("http://trackit.zensar.com/TrackIt/"); 

    WebElement userName= _driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
    WebElement password= _driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    //WebElement submit= _driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
    Actions seriesOfActions = builder.moveToElement(userName).click().sendKeys(userName, "sm38553");
    seriesOfActions.perform();

    Actions action1 = builder.moveToElement(password).click().sendKeys(password, "Zensar#123");
    action1.perform();

   // _driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();


   _driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();


}
```

}

The selenium test fails with the below message

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"Login"}
```

Please let me know what needs to be done.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I did your way by providing an id and by name too, but could not get results.It throws the same error.Also, I am aware that my code above is wrong(when no selector is provided), but I need to know whats the correct approach for it.Please see my code as below
    package home_page;

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class OpenURL {

@Test
public void openSoftwareTesting(){

    WebDriver _driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    _driver.get("http://trackit.zensar.com/TrackIt/"); 

    WebElement userName= _driver.findElement(By.name("userName"));
    WebElement password= _driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
    //WebElement submit= _driver.findElement(By.name("submit"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(_driver);
    Actions seriesOfActions = builder.moveToElement(userName).click().sendKeys(userName, "sm38553");
    seriesOfActions.perform();

    Actions action1 = builder.moveToElement(password).click().sendKeys(password, "Zensar#123");
    action1.perform();

   // _driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();


   _driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();


}
```

}

The JSP code

```
    <tr>
        <td><s:textfield name="userName" label="User Name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><s:password name="password" label="Password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><s:submit id="submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
```

And the selenium error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"submit"}
```

Comment: I see no element with the id of "submit" on that page. I see a login button that has a complex ID. So where has this "submit" ID come from? Selenium appears, to me, to be throwing an exception for the right reason here. The element simply isn't there.

Comment: This is obvious, no? Inspect the HTML. Is there anything with an ID of "Login"? Nope, just like the error says.

Comment: Can you try with [`By.ById("submit")`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ById.html#By.ById%28java.lang.String%29) ?

Answer (score 1):

`<s:submit value="Login" />`

will result, according to the Struts2 theme you are using, in an HTML like

`<input type="submit" value="Login" id="someGeneratedId" />`.

To make it work, simply give it an ID:

`<s:submit value="Login" id="submit" />`

<sub>Note: you can use `name` attribute too, as in your commented code, but this would also post the button's value to the action, and this is generally undesired (unless, for example, you need to discriminate which button was pressed in a form with multiple submit buttons).

Since it is more clean with an ID, go that way.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[6]")).submit();

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FireFox as a browser install the Selenium IDE plugin http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp and then you can manually step through the process to see how Selenium identifies your login button.